# javascript / jquery modify query string parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I need to add or, if it already exists, modify one parameter of a URL query-string.

If I for example want to set `param` to the value `newvalue`,

`http://example.org/file.php` should lead to `http://example.org/file.php?param=newvalue`

`http://example.org/file.php?abc=def` should lead to `http://example.org/file.php?abc=def&param=newvalue`

`http://example.org/file.php?param=oldValue` should lead to `http://example.org/file.php?param=newvalue`

I know about the [URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/) library, but it's smallest possible size of 21kb (non-gziped) is too big for me.

I am looking for either a small library to modify url-query-strings, or a small piece of code which does this for me.

Comment: If you are only doing it for one specific parameter, just use string manipulation or regular expressions.

Comment: i'm thinking that when file.php finishes loading, make an ajax call to file.php?...blabla...&param=new value but it would loop on and on unless you check $_GET for param=newvalue... i don't know how to code this idea quickly enough

Comment: do you need to just change the appearance of the url or actuallr re-direct and rerun the script?

Comment: `document.location.search = 'param=newValue;'`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen That's what I am doing at the moment. `location.href = location.href.replace(/([?&]param)=([^&#]*)/g, '$1=' + "newvalue");` is my replacement function. But this doesn't work if `param` is not set yet. There are also multiple other checks necessary, for example if theres a hash-tag (fragment), or any query parameters are set yet etc. etc..

Comment: @PatrickGunderson it should redirect using `location.href = `

Comment: @Jai `.indexOf()` is not a property of the `location` element. But `.toString().indexOf("?")` is going to work, I think. I posted my (pretty long) version as answer below, but am still looking for a better solution. (I would prefer utilizing a small library tbh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution in all JS, although it would make sense to make this a combo js/php script

```
var myParam = "foo"
var oldValue = "bar"
var newValue = "fighters"

var queryPairs = window.location.search.substr(1).split("&");
var queryParams = [];
queryPairs.forEach(function(element, index, array){
    var pair = element.split("=");
    queryParams[pair[0]] = pair[1];
})

if (queryParams[myParam] == oldValue){
    queryParams[myParam] = newValue;
    queryPairs = [];
    for (var index in queryParams){
        queryPairs.push(index + "=" + queryParams[index]);
    }
    var baseUrl = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
    var newSearch = queryPairs.join("&")
    var newUrl = baseUrl + "?" + newSearch
    window.location = newUrl;
}
```

Comment: to simply assign myParam if it is not yet set (and not reset if already set), you can change the expression `if (queryParams[myParam] == oldValue)` to `if (typeof(queryParams[myParam]) == "undefined")`

Answer (score -1):

My (pretty long) version:

```
if (location.search.match(/([?&]param)=([^&#]*)/g)) {
    location.search = location.search.replace(/([?&]param)=([^&#]*)/g, '$1=' + newvalue);
} else if (location.search.match(/([&][^&#]*)=/g)) {
    location.search = location.search + "&param=" + newvalue;
} else {
    location.search = location.search + "?param=" + newvalue;
}
```